# Freyja: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'log2'

Tags: python, command-line

I'm new to Freyja tool. I have installed all the dependencies this tool requires.
This is the GitHub link of the tool: https://github.com/andersen-lab/Freyja

It's ok when I tried to generate the variant file and depth file using the following command:

```
freyja variants /my_path/my_bam.bam --variants /my_path/test/output_vat.tsv --depths /my_path/test/output_depth.depth --ref /my_path/my_ref.fsa
```

But the problem raised when I called:

```
freyja demix /my_path/test/output_vat.tsv /my_path/test/output_depth.depth --output /my_path/test/output_file.tsv
```

And the following are the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6296, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'log2'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/bin/freyja", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/freyja/_cli.py", line 73, in demix
    sample_strains, abundances, error = solve_demixing_problem(df_barcodes,

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/freyja/sample_deconv.py", line 129, in solve_demixing_problem
    dep = np.log2(depths+1)

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2168, in __array_ufunc__
    return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)

  File "/mnt/data/project/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 399, in array_ufunc
    result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Series which has no callable log2 method
```

I tried re-installed all the dependencies. The Series seem to be an object of pandas, which does not have 'log2' attribute, but I don't know how to solve this since I was just using tool command on terminal instead of coding my stuff.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please post errors as text, not image